# How to install dependencies with Composer before moving to server with Gitlab CI

Tags: php, docker, composer-php, gitlab

I've got a Gitlab repo with .php-files, that gets deployed via this rsync command with Gitlab CI:

```
- rsync -avz -e "ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa -p $SERVER_PORT" /builds/account-name/group-name/project-name/* $SERVER_USER@$SERVER_HOST/$SERVER_DOMAIN
```

Where `/builds/account-name/group-name/project-name/*` is the root of our repository.

Now I want to add a step that installs Composer dependencies before transferring the repository to our server, but I can't figure out how to get to the installed dependencies in the deploy-stage.
The composer.json-file is located in `/1/src/`:

The `build` step I've added before the deploy script works, and looks like this:

```
build_master:
  image: composer
  stage: build
  only:
    - dev
  script:
    - composer install -d /builds/account-name/group-name/project-name/1/src/ --ignore-platform-reqs
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - vendor/
    expire_in: 30 minutes
```

The logs in Gitlab show that the packages are all being installed, but when it tries to upload artifacts for the job this shows:

```
Uploading artifacts for successful job
 Uploading artifacts...
 WARNING: vendor/: no matching files                
 ERROR: No files to upload                          
 Job succeeded
```

I was hoping that composer would install everything into the `vendor` folder, with Gitlab storing that in it's artifacts. In the deploy step I was thinking of adding another rsync line like the one above, and changing the source folder to `vendor/` and the destination to `$SERVER_USER@$SERVER_HOST/$SERVER_DOMAIN/1/src/vendor`.

I'm unable to figure out where this goes wrong. Maybe it has something to do with the artifact-vendor folder also needing to be relative to `1/src/`, and I was wondering if I really need two rsync lines in the deploy script, instead of installing the composer packages into the right folder in the /builds/.../project-name/ folder directly, so that only one rsync action is necessary.

Comment: Why do you use absolute paths in your command and not a relative one?

Comment: @NicoHaase I wasn't aware of the `$CI_PROJECT_DIR/*` variable in Gitlab, but that is a lot better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Gitlab's documentation [page](https://docs.gitlab.com/12.10/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html#defining-artifacts-in-gitlab-ciyml) :

> All paths to files and directories are relative to the repository that was cloned during the build.

And `artifacts:paths` are also relative to the root of your projects build.

When running composer in `1/src`, the `vendor` directory will be created at `1/src/vendor` which is the path you want the assets to be uploaded from.

Your job config would be :

```yaml
build_master:
  # ...
  script:
    - composer install -d 1/src --ignore-platform-reqs
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - 1/src/vendor
```

That said, there's no problem in running `composer install` at the root of your project if it's the directory in which `vendor` is supposed to be.

Keep in mind that in order to optimize transfers you can also add an additional script line in your build process to zip your dependencies directory.

Comment: I've got the chance to implement this today and it works exactly like you describe it; in my build-step I've added a relative path in the `-d` argument for composer, and used the relative path to the vendor folder in the artifacts.
The deploy step automatically contains the artifacts files.